# reset select options using javascript ES6

Tags: javascript

I have div block with id name `fields`. Inside this div I have couple of select boxes with class name `select-box`. I'm trying to reset the select boxes when button clicked. I'm writing below code inside that click event. But I don't see select boxes reset. Could you please help me to find out a way to get this done. thank you!

```
let selectInputs = document.getElementById('fields').querySelectorAll('.select-box');

for(let selectInput of selectInputs) {
  selectInput.prop(selectedIndex, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is the div `<div class="fields">` or `<div id="fields">`? Your code says it's `<div id="fields">` but your description says it's `<div class="fields">`

Comment: did you read the error message?

Comment: 'fields' is an ID name not class name I just updated my question.

Comment: Off topic: you can shorten your selector to `document.querySelectorAll('#fields .select-box');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a jquery function. set directly selectedIndex

```
let selectInputs = document.getElementById('fields').querySelectorAll('.select-box');

for(let selectInput of selectInputs) {
  selectInput.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the html?